# Javascript to get youtube video id (regex issue)

Tags: javascript, regex, youtube

I use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        var field1 = document.getElementById("field_wy4dm0");
        field1.addEventListener("change", combineFields);

        function combineFields() {
            var val1 = field1.value;
            var val1re = val1.match("/(.*)?")[1];
            var str = document.getElementById("changeThisMovie").innerHTML;
            var res = str.replace("yeC3AisTs2Y", val1re);
            document.getElementById("changeThisMovie").innerHTML = res;
        }
    });
</script>
```

It works great to get a youtube video id which is located between "/" and "?" in the "val1" var and replace the old video id "yeC3AisTs2Y" that is located inside a div with the id="changeThisMovie" with the new one ("val1re").

**The problem is it adds "?" in the end of the new video id so instead of getting:**

> /videoid?feature=embed...

**I get:**

> /videoid??feature=embed...

**How do i fix this?**

Thanks!!!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have a regex problem (consider changing topic and tags...), but if you could post actual values we'd know for sure

Comment: Thanks. what "actual values" you mean?

Comment: What values are in `val1` (`field1.value`) & `str`?

Comment: the val1 is a youtube full url (that is inserted in text field) and the str is also a youtube full url. i'm trying to change the str video id to the val1 video id.

Comment: Please provide actual data, not description. something like `val1 = "http://www.youtube.com?a=b&c=d"`

Comment: val1 = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/yeC3AisTs2Y?feature=oembed&modestbranding=0&theme=light&autoplay=1&hd=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1&controls=0"  and str = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/l974FFSmNFI?feature=oembed&modestbranding=0&theme=light&autoplay=1&hd=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1&controls=0"

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to escape the ? In your regex to mean the literal ? symbol - regex will interpret as ignore previous block

So you could try as follows:

```
 var val1re = val1.match("/(.*)\?")[1];
```

Comment: Thanks filype, but now it's just ignoring the "?" property... (it returns the value that comes after "/" but doesn't stop after the "?")